# Get back computed hash value when using SHA512Managed

Tags: c#, .net

this may sound non sense, actually in may application I use to store password string in DB by computing to hash using SHA512Managed, I am writing a utility using which an admin can send mails to users using that EmailAddress and Password, but I can't pass that coputed value as a password to SMTP. is there any way to solve this?

Or a better cryptogarphy way?

Or any way to send mail in this condition?

Thanx

Comment: OMG that sounds confused and twisted. I hope you are not running anything important and people are careful

Comment: @sehe which statement in this question is confusing?

Comment: People should add reason of down voting the question. I know it is not possible I am looking for alternate ways.

Answer (score 2):

You cant, SHA512 I believe is not possible to be decrypted, which is why it is used.

All you can do is keep some form of data on your users aka, secret questions, and they must match them and then it will send them a new password.

Any properly encrypted password is not abled to be decrypted

Comment: problem is not recovering password.

Answer (score 1):

You should *NOT* be using OR sending your users password, or even a simple hash of that, for that matter.

If you want to enable password reset, you should hand the users a TOKEN (which is NOT the hash of anyone's password). This token should be separately stored in a table and should have a set expiry.

You can use any kind of cryptographic hash (SHA512 is just fine) to 'encode' special information.

--- I fully missed what you meant by 'I cannot...as a password to SMTP'

If you need the original password of your users to even send mail, than - well that *is* twisted. Perhaps you could elaborate/explain this part

Comment: but how can i use that computed hash as a password to send mail?

Comment: Ask your mail server's admin? What mail server? Database backed? Virtual users? it might be possible, but I'm at a loss why you would want to use SMTP passwords if - quite obviously - you don't have a very good grasp of security principles. SMTP will not become secure by the act of authenticating connections.

Answer (score 0):

SHA-512 is a one-way hash, meaning you can't take the hash value and determine what string/value was used to generate that hash. Technically, there can be an infinite number of strings/values that would generate the same hash.

If you want to be able to get the value back, you should use [encryption](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/SimpleEncryption.aspx), not hashing.